# Multiple node network communication over I²C

Tags: i2c, attiny, networking, network

I am working on a project where I want to send data from and to different Arduinos on a network. At the moment I²C seems the best option for my needs since I can specify where to send the data. But using this method I have a bit of an issue I can't seem to find a solution for :(.

I will try to explain my problem using the following image:

[image]

In the backend all the nodes are connected like in the first image (above the example network). But the nodes may be connected in a different sequence by a user. See the example network.

In this example network, the node with ID 1 needs to send data to ID 10 and not to any other node on the network. Node ID 12 also needs to send data to node ID 10, but no other nodes. Etc. Etc. Etc. But the node that needs to send data to the next node doesn't know the id of the node it needs to send to.

So at first the nodes need to find out what nodes they are connected to and where they need to send their data.

I thought of doing this by connecting a wire between each node (blue wire in possible solution) and when a node gets added to the network the nodes send a high signal over the blue wire and sends its ID to all nodes on the network and then all nodes on the network check if they receive a high signal and an ID.

If this is true they will send its id to the node that has been added. This works fine if you add a node one by one to the network. But it fails when you replace a node in the middle of the network or disconnect power from the network.

What would be the best way to do this (I am also open to use different data transfer protocols)?

Comment: Do nodes really need to know which node is next door?

Comment: i think yeah because I2c requires an adres where it needs to transmit its data to. (and the node must only send its data to the node that is physically next) But if you think it is not necessary let me know

Comment: What purpose does the concept of "next door" achieve?

Comment: it makes sure the data goes through the network in chronological order

Comment: What do you mean "through the network in chronological order"?

Comment: With I2C your master communicates with a slave. It doesn't care where on the bus that slave is.

Comment: If you look at the example network the node with ID 1 must only send its data to the node with ID 10 and not to the nodes with other ID's. It is just something i want

Comment: So you send it to node 10.

Comment: Or are you looking to avoid bus contention in a multi-master scenario?

Comment: Yes indeed but node ID 1 doesnt know that to node it needs to send to has ID 10 how do i figure that out?

Comment: But you just stated that 1 has to send to 10.

Comment: yes what you just said is the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76748/discussion-between-futurecake-and-majenko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds (after discussion) like what you are after is actually a *mesh* of multiple *peer to peer* devices.  That is, lots of devices, each one has multiple dedicated communication links each directly going to another device.

If you had enough UART ports you could create individual UART links between nodes. The bets Arduinos only have a handful of those, and the UNO only one.  So that's not really practical.

You could possibly do it with SPI if you wanted to put a lot of work in to developing a decent control protocol to go along with it.  Something along the lines of BUSRQ/BUSACK signalling:

```
BUSRQ: Signalling line pulled HIGH by resistor. All nodes INPUT.
BUSACK: Signalling line pulled HIGH by resistor. All nodes OPEN-DRAIN & LOW.
SS: Direct 1:1 GPIO links between nodes - all pulled HIGH. All nodes INPUT.

Node 1                   Node 2                  Node X
RELEASE BUSACK
DRIVE BUSRQ (OD Low)     Sees BUSRQ fall         Sees BUSRQ fall
                         RELEASE BUSACK          (could be busy...)
                                                 RELEASE BUSACK
Sees BUSACK rise
DRIVE BUSACK
SS Node 2 LOW            Sees SS go LOW
Send SPI data            Receives SPI data
SS Node 2 INPUT          Sees SS go HIGH
RELEASE BUSRQ                                    Sees BUSRQ rise
                         Sees BUSRQ rise         Drive BUSACK
                         Drive BUSACK
```

Only once all nodes have released BUSACK will the requesting node be able to send any data, and once a node has released BUSACK it knows that it must never send any data.  The requesting node has basically locked the bus from other nodes accessing it.

It's not perfect, and doesn't handle multiple devices requesting the bus at the same moment, but it does prevent one device trying to send while another is actively sending.